# disable https for single page with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have tried some htaccess senteces but it doesn't work for me. I need to use whole site with https except one page it requires http connection from another site so i need to disable https for this page.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} \/exp\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,NC]
```

browser says it seems there is too many redirections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !exp\.php$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```