# Https to http redirect using htaccess for a single PHP file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, ssl, https

I am trying to redirect https://demo.aurazoscript.com/surf.php?id=15 to http://demo.aurazoscript.com/surf.php?id=15. I tried the following in .htaccess but that doesn't work. It turns off forced HTTPS redirection for the whole website which I don't want. I only want it to be turned off for that single page `surf.php`.

I tried in .htaccess

```
# FORCE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/(surf.php)
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# DISABLE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/(surf.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I am using Flexible SSL from CloudFlare.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable https for single page with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084170/disable-https-for-single-page-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

I think you do it opposite way , try this at the beginning of `.htaccess` file  after `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^surf\.php   http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^surf\.php  https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test .

Comment: Tried. Not working. You can visit the website and check. This code is still there in my .htaccess file.

Comment: @AppleBux did you clear browser cache? i there any change ? let me know which request not work and which one works

Comment: Wait a minute. After pasting your code after `RewriteEngine On` the browser quits and returns `demo.aurazoscript.com redirected you too many times.` This means your code has some error. Its not working. Please check.

Comment: @AppleBux are there any other rules ?